# Is this code secure enough for a minimum and maximum int

Tags: php

So, I have created some code in php, and now I want to know if its "secure enough". This is the code:

```php
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
if ($amount < 1) { die("Min amount is 1."); }
if ($amount > 20) { die("Max amount is 20."); }
// More stuff here
```

Is it possible, to for example somehow get the `$amount` set to 50, and still let it work? After this it will send a `file_get_contents` to a webpage with the number, for example: `https://example.com/amount.php?a=15`. Is it possible to get that 15 to be 50 at the "More stuff here" part.

I'm just curious, that's all.

---

**EDITS**

Here is the html Im using;

```html
<form method="POST">
    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-user" id="amount" name="amount" min="1" max="20" value="1"><br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Then this is my full php (for example)

```php
if (isset($_POST['amount'])) {
   $amount = $_POST['amount'];
   if ($amount < 1) { die("Min amount is 1."); }
   if ($amount > 20) { die("Max amount is 20."); }
   $conn->query("INSERT INTO my_table (amount) VALUES ('$amount')");
   file_get_contents("https://example.com/file.php?a=".$amount); // POINT A
}
```

Is it somehow possible to send at "POINT A" a other number? Like `50`?

Comment: _Is it possible to get that 15 to be 50 at the "More stuff here" part._ Yes `$amount = 50;` or even `$amount += 35;`

Comment: But I mean by `$_POST['amount']` if users can somehow put something in the number input place, and then get it to 50, and bypassing those 2 if thingies that check if its under 1 and above 20.

Comment: Do you expect to handle fractions of an item, like `1.5`?, also nothing is going to work for `?a=15` as your reading from `$_POST['amount']` not `$_GET['a']`

Comment: It sends at `// More stuff here` the request to `https://example.com/amount.php?a=$amount` with some more variables added in. I'm asking if they can somehow make the `$amount` variable higher then 20, and still let the script send the request.

Comment: no it's not, but if you change the second line to `$amount = (float)$_POST['amount'];` then it would be sufficient :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to:

```
$amount = (int)$_POST['amount'];
```

or else the user can enter something such as:

```
3*3
```

which can cause issues for your `file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/amount.php?a=3*3' )`

---

A truly problematic scenario would be this input:

```
7&a=8734
```

which would send the request as `file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/amount.php?a=7&a=8734' )`

The second `a`'s value would win so the example.com server would interpret your request as if you had sent `file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/amount.php?a=8734' )`

This "attack" works because of PHP's type-juggling and that it converts `7&a=8734` into simply `7` for purposes of the comparison but you are sending the non-juggled version on to example.com.

This is why `$amount = (int)$_POST['amount'];` is the proper solution.

Comment: My question more was like: It sends at `// More stuff here` the request to `https://example.com/amount.php?a=$amount` with some more variables added in. I'm asking if they can somehow make the `$amount` variable higher then 20, and still let the script send the request.

Comment: @AaronJonk Yes, I saw it. `min="1" max="20"` won't save you because it is super trivial to open up the web browser's console and remove those. HTML is client-side so there is zero security to be had. Your server accepts `$_POST['amount']` so you need to properly handle that value on the server-side.

Comment: But its nice for the people to know that there is a maximum of 20. (As I am using bootstrap, and it will pop up something if you try to get over it). It's more about if its possible to do harm to my website.

Comment: @AaronJonk Okay, so what part of my answer is confusing? Simply put, your code is open for pwnage as it stands.

Comment: But I would like to know how it would to be possible to do any harm to this exact code

Comment: I explained the harm for `file_get_contents()`. Now that you've added SQL to your question then you need to check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2191572  because there is zero reason for me to continue explaining anything. One day when your system is hacked then feel free to re-read my answer.

Comment: do we know amount can't be float? otherwise you might want to cast it to (float) instead of (int)

Comment: @hanshenrik OP's HTML does not make use of the `step` attribute so I think it is safe to assume whole numbers.

Answer (score 2):

One example of how your code is problematic:

By posting a value like this:

```
1'),('50'),('42
```

a user can insert multiple values into `my_table`, any values they want to try.

[That string is >= 1, and <= 20.](https://3v4l.org/04oEq)

It's simple to defeat client-side validation, it really isn't even necessary to use a browser to post values to your script.

[You need to bind that value to a prepared statement instead of including it directly in the SQL string to prevent this type of mischief.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (amount) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute([$amount]);
```

You must do this with any *value* you need to use in a query. Don't depend on filtering, escaping, or casting. It's not that they can't work, it's just that if you're in the habit of using variables directly in your query like `INSERT ... VALUES ('$amount')` you depend on your ability to remember to filter/escape/cast 100% of the time, and we're only human.

Answer (score 1):

**Never trust user input**

That in and of itself is not secure. Users can manipulate your forms via inspection tools or post anything they want with post man. A ! 1 3.5. All are viable inputs. This also includes XSS, SQL injection, etc etc.

That said you need to sanitize your inputs first. I would suggest using the is_numeric function first then dying if it returns false. After that you know then it's in fact a number which you can check the range on.

```
if(!is_numeric($amount))
    die();
```

Comment: Is it then possible that if I put the input to, for example; `echo "hi";` it will actually do it? I want to know how it would be able to get bypassed..

Comment: It is possible, though XSS is a bigger concern than echoing something. Always sanitize your data. strip_slashes is good but using a preg_replace with a good pattern is the best way to sanitize it.

Comment: Yes it's possible still.

Answer (score 0):

the other answers are excellent in explaining why it's not sufficient, but none show how to properly validate the input, which can be done with filter_var() and would look something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['amount'])) {
   $amount = $_POST['amount'];
   if(false===($amount=filter_var($amount,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)){
      http_response_code(400); // HTTP 400 Bad Request
      die("invalid amount (not a number)"); // show error page
   }
   // $amount is guaranteed to be a valid floating-point number,
   // also filter_var() did the typecast for us,
   // so $amount is now a php-native float.
   if ($amount < 1) { die("Min amount is 1."); }
   if ($amount > 20) { die("Max amount is 20."); }
   $conn->query("INSERT INTO my_table (amount) VALUES ('$amount')");
   file_get_contents("https://example.com/file.php?a=".$amount); // POINT A
}
```

- if $amount can only be integers, not floats, then use FILTER_VALIDATE_INT instead of FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT